# Best encryption algorithm for encrypting text messages

Tags: encryption, decryption

I want to develop an application that allows users to send and receive encrypted text messages, could you please suggest to me what is the best symmetric encryption algorithm that can be suitable for my purpose.

Comment: That's too broad my friend, one needs to write a book to answer you, please try to be specific.

Comment: I'm afraid that adding the word "symmetric" doesn't really make the question less broad. There is a standard for [off-the-record or OTR messaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging) that might get you started. From reading that you'll see that a secure messaging system is more than just picking an encryption algorithm.